# Java Fair Reentrant lock isn't fair in multiple iterations

Tags: java, reentrantlock

I am trying to write a test, in which I want to demonstrate the difference between fair and unfair Reentrant locks.
The test uses `ThreadPoolExecutor` and consists of multiple iterations, each of which has the following steps:

1. Create a fair lock to test and semaphore with 1 permit to manage the time of releasing the lock.
2. Acquire the semaphore.
3. Submit a task, which acquires the lock, and waits for semaphore to release.
4. Submit multiple "enumerated" tasks, each of which tries to acquire the lock and then updates the shared `AtomicInteger` state.
5. Release the semaphore and wait for all tasks to finish.

So for the fair lock the final value of shared state have to be equal to the index of the last task.
But the test fails in ~ 50% of all executions.

My code looks like this:

```
    @Test
    void should_be_fair() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        int iterationsCount = 100;
        int waitingThreadsCount = 5;

        ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);
        Semaphore unlockingSemaphore = new Semaphore(1);
        boolean wasAnyThreadUnfair = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < iterationsCount; i++) {
            unlockingSemaphore.acquire();
            ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(waitingThreadsCount + 1);
            Future<?> lockingFuture = executor.submit(() -> {
                try {
                    lock.lock();
                    unlockingSemaphore.acquire();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                } finally {
                    unlockingSemaphore.release();
                    lock.unlock();
                }
            });
            AtomicInteger sharedState = new AtomicInteger();
            List<Future<Integer>> futures = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, waitingThreadsCount)
                    .sequential()
                    .mapToObj(j -> executor.submit(() -> {
                        try {
                            lock.lock();
                            System.out.println("Acquiring lock for j=" + j);
                            return sharedState.updateAndGet((k) -> j);
                        } finally {
                            lock.unlock();
                        }
                    }))
                    .toList();
            unlockingSemaphore.release();
            lockingFuture.get();
            futures.forEach(f -> {
                try {
                    f.get();
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            });
            executor.shutdown();
            System.out.println("Ended " + i + "-th cycle with the last index=" + sharedState.get());
            if (sharedState.get() != waitingThreadsCount) {
                wasAnyThreadUnfair = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        Assertions.assertThat(wasAnyThreadUnfair).isFalse();
    }
```

**Question**:

What's the problem with this test? What can I fix to get the test passed in 100% of executions?

Comment: How do you think this is testing for the fairness of a lock?

Comment: please check javadoc: `Note however, that fairness of locks does not guarantee fairness of thread scheduling. Thus, one of many threads using a fair lock may obtain it multiple times in succession while other active threads are not progressing and not currently holding the lock`

Comment: @MarkRotteveel All tasks should acquire the lock in the order from 1 to `waitingThreadsCount`, because they were submitted in this order. Do I misunderstand something?

Comment: not 100% sure, but maybe you could replace the "futures.forEach f -> f.get()" loop with a call to "executor.invokeAll()" which will wait for all of them to finish; shutdown doesn't wait, it just tells the executor to not accept any more Tasks (this is just a cursory glance, I may be completely wrong)

Comment: @AndreyMironov submitted != started. In your current thread submitting tasks, it will add them to a queue and continue on, unblocked. It's on another thread to consume those added tasks, so your thread could very well queue all of those tasks before any of them begin. The starting order here isn't guaranteed, though `lockingFuture` is at least marginally more likely to begin before the rest of them.

Comment: @Rogue they are being started, f.get() inside the futures.forEach loop.

Comment: @VioletRosenzweig that's _after_ the submission of all tasks, and will not affect the starting order. You can wait on a `Future<?>` that will never arrive, after all. In this case, we're blocking the submitting thread in-sequence with the futures that are scheduled, but nothing stops tasks 2-5 from starting/completing before task 1 while we block on it, nor does anything ensure task 5 comes after task 4, etc. The newer facilities for doing this type of order guarantee is usually done through `CompletableFuture<?>` or somesuch.

Comment: @AndreyMironov Task submission is separate from task scheduling on a thread, and from that thread getting scheduled on a CPU, and as Andrey B. Panfilov quoted, the order of scheduling of threads may be different and is not fair. This may very well mean that the task with the highest value of `j` may get scheduled and run before any other task, so it is first in line for the lock. So, the lock may be fair, but there is no deterministic order for your threads arriving at the lock, and thus no deterministic order for which one finishes last.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, Roque Thank you! That's right, the problem was in my wrong decision, that the order of tasks submitting is the same as the order of lock acquisition. I fixed the test and updated the question. Unfortunately, the test related to unfair lock doesn't pass anymore, but it is another problem)

Comment: @AndreyMironov You seem to have resolved your issue, but posted that resolution in your question. That's not how things are done here. Please consider removing that update from your question, and posting it as an answer to your question instead, clearly showing what you changed in the code. It's much more helpful to the community to have answers to questions rather than having resolution buried in the comments, or inserted into the question. That said, that is the best [java] question from a new poster that I have seen for a long time - well done.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was in the order of acquiring the lock by tasks. The order of submitting is not quaranteed to be equal to the order of starting.
So I added the usage of `Awaitility` library to wait until each task is blocked by lock acquiring. Unfortunately, the test related to unfair lock doesn't pass anymore, but it is another problem.

```
   @Test
    void should_be_fair() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        Assertions.assertThat(wasAnyThreadUnfair(new ReentrantLock(true), 100, 5)).isFalse();
    }

    @Test
    // TODO: doesn't pass
    void should_be_unfair() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        Assertions.assertThat(wasAnyThreadUnfair(new ReentrantLock(false), 100, 5)).isTrue();
    }

    private boolean wasAnyThreadUnfair(ReentrantLock lock, int iterationsCount, int waitingThreadsCount)
            throws InterruptedException {
        Semaphore unlockingSemaphore = new Semaphore(1);
        boolean wasAnyThreadUnfair = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < iterationsCount; i++) {
            unlockingSemaphore.acquire();
            ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(waitingThreadsCount + 1);
            Future<?> lockingFuture = executor.submit(() -> {
                try {
                    lock.lock();
                    unlockingSemaphore.acquire();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                } finally {
                    unlockingSemaphore.release();
                    lock.unlock();
                }
            });
            AtomicInteger sharedState = new AtomicInteger();
            List<Future<Integer>> futures = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, waitingThreadsCount)
                    .mapToObj(j -> {
                        Future<Integer> submitted = executor.submit(() -> {
                            try {
                                lock.lock();
                                System.out.println("Acquiring lock for j=" + j);
                                return sharedState.updateAndGet((k) -> j);
                            } finally {
                                lock.unlock();
                            }
                        });
                        await().atMost(150, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).until(() -> lock.getQueueLength() == j);
                        return submitted;
                    })
                    .toList();
            unlockingSemaphore.release();
            executor.shutdown();
            executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            System.out.println("Ended " + i + "-th cycle with the last index=" + sharedState.get());
            if (sharedState.get() != waitingThreadsCount) {
                wasAnyThreadUnfair = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        return wasAnyThreadUnfair;
    }
```

Comment: Regarding your comment about the unfair lock: a lock with fair=false is not guaranteed to be unfair, it is just not required to be fair (and even with fair=true is fairness not 100% guaranteed).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel ok, so if I want to demonstrate (and understand))) the differences provided by this flag, I need to find some platform architecture, where they are +- reproducible, right?

Comment: Basically yes, but in practice I think it will be hard to do anyway.